# How to stop a running program in C?

Tags: c, linux, orange-pi

I have a problem.I've written a program in `C` for armbian.

I am using `RTKLIB` software for GPS data conversion from `ubx` to `RTCM3`.

I get some data from serial port and start `str2str`(rtklib software).

It creates this command to run

```
str2str -in tcpsvr://:2101#ubx -out serial://ttyS2:115200#rtcm3
```

and call system function to run this command. It is successful, but when I send a new command, I want it to stop the str2str software.

I've tried the `exit(0)` and it stops my software. I don't want to stop my software. I want to stop `str2str` and create a new command and run it again.

How can I do it? I am not good with the linux environment.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to something readable

Comment: Terrible question, hard to answer.

Comment: What function did you use to run str2srt ? , if you can get its PID you can kill it.

Comment: I create a string array  char command_run[256]; and run command with system(command_run);

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you find out how to search for the str2str process you want to kill, and get the PID. A stackoverflow search will reveal this and then use the PID to kill the process. Unless RTKLIB has a process to do this directly.

Comment: can I use "-pkill str2str" instead of PID. In C, I need to find PID number and than close it. but this can be easier and faster way if it is works.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.